# Spring security gives access denied on /actuator/health

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am trying to understand why Spring security gives access denied on /actuator/health
Can anyone spot the problem?

The logs says:

```
27/02/2020 11:24:57.902 [http-nio-4104-exec-1] [,,] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/actuator/health'; against '/actuator/**'
27/02/2020 11:24:57.902 [http-nio-4104-exec-1] [,,] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /actuator/health; Attributes: [hasIpAddress('127.0.0.1/32')]
27/02/2020 11:24:57.902 [http-nio-4104-exec-1] [,,] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@187dbd2d: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
27/02/2020 11:24:57.909 [http-nio-4104-exec-1] [,,] DEBUG o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased - Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@790ce264, returned: -1
27/02/2020 11:24:57.912 [http-nio-4104-exec-1] [,,] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter - Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
at no.gjensidige.bank.nasasupport.jwt.JwtTokenFilter.doFilterInternal(JwtTokenFilter.java:60) [15 skipped]
at ch.qos.logback.access.tomcat.LogbackValve.invoke(LogbackValve.java:256) [41 skipped]
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830) [13 skipped]


http
                .antMatcher("/**") // If you want to override the security provided by Spring Boot.
                .cors().and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/actuator/**")
                .access("hasIpAddress('127.0.0.1/32')")
                .antMatchers("/api")
                .hasAnyAuthority("not important")
  .antMatchers("/actuator/health", "/open/**")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .denyAll();
```

Anyone spot the error? I am using spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE

I had to add this:
`@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {UserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration.class}) to` remove the default generated password. I get the same error if UserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration is excluded or not.

Answer (score 2):

We use this configuration to achieve what seems similar to your requirements: The `health` and `prometheus` endpoints must be accessible without authentication. Any request is permitted from `localhost` (running Docker container in our case) or from anywhere for authenticated users.

```
private static final String ACTUATOR_BASE                = "/actuator";
private static final String MATCHERS_ACTUATOR_HEALTH     = ACTUATOR_BASE + "/health";
private static final String MATCHERS_ACTUATOR_PROMETHEUS = ACTUATOR_BASE + "/prometheus";

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(MATCHERS_ACTUATOR_HEALTH).permitAll()
        .antMatchers(MATCHERS_ACTUATOR_PROMETHEUS).permitAll()
        .anyRequest()
        .access("hasIpAddress('127.0.0.0/8') or hasIpAddress('::1') or isAuthenticated()")
        .and()
        .httpBasic()
        .and()
        .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you add the Actuator to a secure application you get an additional filter chain that applies only to the actuator endpoints. It has an order of `ManagementServerProperties.BASIC_AUTH_ORDER`. If you want your application security rules to apply to the actuator endpoints you can add a filter chain ordered earlier than the actuator one, this can be done using `ManagementServerProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER`. 
In short, try doing this:

```
@Configuration
@Order(ManagementServerProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
public class ApplicationConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    // your implementation
}
```

[Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.14.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/ManagementServerProperties.html#ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)

Comment: I am using Spring Boot 2.2. ManagementServerProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER) is only in Spring Boot 1.x it seems

Comment: Looks like they have removed separate security auto-configuration for Actuator since Spring Boot 2.0. So changing the filter order may not work. What I would try first of all is moving the permitAll() rule above the access() rule in the current implementation. Also, are you trying to reach `/actuator/health` from 127.0.0.1?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.
I don't know why our configuration didn't work, but I change the order. I defined `/actuator/health` permitAll() first, then defined `/actuator/**` access after.

```
http.antMatcher("/**")
            .cors().and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/actuator/health", "/open/**")
            .permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/actuator/**")
            .access("hasIpAddress('127.0.0.1/32')")
            .antMatchers("/api")
            .hasAnyAuthority("not important")
            .anyRequest()
            .denyAll();
```